# Phonegap Build error: plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm:media

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

After building my app with dreamweaver and i added this plugin `<plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />` to my config.xml to enable my app to play audio files, when i uploaded my zip file to phonegap for the compliation  i got this error, `Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: Media`

Answer (score 0):

@i_user,
welcome to Cordova/Phonegap.

You have three (3) issues.

1. Dreamweaver is not a good tool for Phonegap.
2. You really need to start over with *Phonegap Build*. It is easier to use that most system, but the difference often trips up people
3. When you are looking for plugins to use (for *Phonegap Build*), there are really only two (2) sources available. There is one minor exception.

**On #1**, I recommend you drop the Dreamweaver and the associate tools. They are incomplete and troublesome. You can use the Dreamweaver for HTML design and some CSS, but not much else. It would work for about half of the work you need to do.

As per [the FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/):

> **Q: What is PhoneGap Build, and how is it different from PhoneGap framework?**
>
> A: PhoneGap is a mobile application development framework, based upon the open source Apache Cordova project. It allows you to write an app once with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and then deploy it to a wide range of mobile devices (...)

To be clear, you will only be edit HTML, CSS, Javascript, some easy XML. There are many IDE tools available, including Dreamweaver, Android Studio, Visual Studio - just to name a few.

**On #2**, when using the *Phonegap Build* system, there is only one place to start - [the Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29) There are legacy mistakes in the documentation, but for the most part it is okay.

When developing code, start with you own boilerplate - don't use others, unless they have been recently test. Cordova/Phonegap is a moving target and developers often get tripped up by not readine the [Blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build). As a reference, you can use one of my boilerplates - [An HTML Boilerplate for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html), and here is the latest [Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7)

**On #3**, the two (2) sources are *"core"* and *third-party* plugins.

- On *"core"*plugins, FOR NOW, use this list -> [Cordova "core" plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html)
- On *third-party* plugins, use NPM for [almost all plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/).

**Caveat:** somethings you cannot use the latest version of a plugin with *Phonegap Build*. If this happens, go back at least one version, and try that.

You want to play audio, so here is your plugin as it should be list in your `config.xml`

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />`

These last two links will get you going in the right direction.

- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
- [[NOTE] for New Developers: Top Bloggers for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/topBloggers.html)